# Convert DataLakeFileClient object to java Resource object

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download a file from Azure blob storage and trying to convert it into a `Resource` object. The code should look something like this.

```java
        import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

        public Resource downloadFile() {
             Resource resource;
             DataLakeFileClient fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient("test.txt"); // fileSystemClient is the container location
        
             // code to fetch content present in file client object and assign it to resource;
        
             return resource;
        }
```

I have tried many implementations using `OutputStream` and `InputStream` objects, but unable to find the exact code. Can anyone help me by providing the exact code for the same?

Comment: What is `Resource`? In which package?

Comment: It's from org.springframework.core.io.Resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below Spring boot code to download a file from Azure blob storage and converted it into a Resource object from DataLakeGen2 Storage from Azure Portal.

I have the below blob saved in my storage account container.

[image]

**Code:**

```java
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

@RestController
public class DownloadFile {

    @GetMapping("/download-file")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile() {
        String sasToken = "<storage_account_SAS_Token>"; 
        String accountName = "<Account_name>";
        String containerName = "<Container_Name>"; 
        String fileName = "<Blob_Nmae>";

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint("https://" + accountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net")
                .sasToken(sasToken)
                .buildClient();

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        blobClient.download(outputStream);

        final byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
        Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource(bytes);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

        System.out.println("Blob downloaded successfully: " + fileName);

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .headers(headers)
                .body(resource);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-file-datalake</artifactId>
            <version>12.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully and gives the print statement as **Blob downloaded successfully** as below,

[image]

With the above output port **8080**, I got the blob downloaded at the browser as below,

[image]

And also, I checked this in **Postman** and got the data of that blob as below,

[image]