# Postman returns: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Required query parameter 'file' is not present." no matter what

Tags: spring-boot, postman, azure-blob-storage, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Boot CRUD using reactive programming. I'm using an Azure Blob Container to work with the data. My reading method works just fine. However I can´t test my upload method yet because Postman is always throwing the error:

`400 BAD_REQUEST "Required query parameter 'file' is not present."`

In the beginning I thought it was something wrong with my method, then I change the return type to void and left the body empty and I got the same response from Postman. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with Postman itself.

so far, I have:

1. Enabled "Read files outside working directory"
2. Added a key "file" in the form-data area
3. Removed the key "file" in the form-data area
4. Added the "Content-Type" header with default values: multipart/form-data; boundary=
5. Removed the "Content-Type" header
6. Removed the "Content-Type" header and set one manually

None of these have worked, it throws the same 400 error immediately after pushing the send (POST) button in Postman.

This is the mentioned method:

````
// From service implementation class
@Override
    public Mono<Void> uploadBlob(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String blobName = file.getOriginalFilename();

        if (blobName == null || blobName.isEmpty()) {
            return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file name"));
        }

        logger.info("Uploading blob: {}", blobName);
        return blobContainerAsyncClient.getBlobAsyncClient(blobName)
                .uploadFromFile(file.getResource().getFile().getPath(), true) // true para sobrescribir si ya existe
                .then();
    }

// From controller class
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> uploadBlob(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        return azureBlobService.uploadBlob(file)
                .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().<Void>build());
    }```

Any ideas on this are welcomed.
````

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the following code to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage using Postman.*

**Code :**

```java
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/upload-file")
public class UploadFile {

    private final BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient;

    public UploadFile() {
        String connectionString = "<connec_string>";
        this.blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("<container_name>");
            String originalFileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(originalFileName);

            blobClient.upload(file.getInputStream(), file.getSize(), true);
            System.out.println("Blob uploaded successfully: " + originalFileName);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("Failed to upload the file");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully, as shown below:

[image]

I uploaded a file to Azure Blob Storage using **Postman** as shown below.

[image]

**Azure Portal :**

*The blob was successfully uploaded to Azure Storage in the Azure Portal, as shown below.*

[image]

**Reference:** Refer to my [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76803022/convert-datalakefileclient-object-to-java-resource-object/76811509#76811509) for downloading the blob from Azure Storage.

Comment: You are using a tradicional blocking approach for creating your endpoints, which is fine. I'm using WebFlux which is different from what you shared, however I did the same as you, all my endpoints work except upload which is asking for that required query parameter. Thank you @Dasari